# Having UI issue on Edge browser

Tags: wordpress, compression, frontend, microsoft-edge

I am the new one to understand the edge; we recently created a website using Wordpress. Our website loading is taking a lot of time, so I research on google and finally, I used WP Super Cache plugin, and it was working fine, but the thing is on Edge latest version the whole UI having a problem and it's not opening correctly. Kindly please suggest me how I can solve this problem.

Here is the [**URL**](https://jaicoupons.com)

Here are the Images: 
[Edge View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZh79.png) and [Normal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHBTx.jpg)

Comment: what do you use the theme or custom theme in website??

Comment: @PriyankaModi thanks for your response, we are using wp-coupons theme

Comment: So, you have check the theme setting by wp-admin backend side

Comment: @PriyankaModi Yes